# Lebesgue integral for a non-negative, measurable and bounded function

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Consider the measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$. Let $f$ be a measurable, non-negative and bounded function. Show that the $\mu$-integral of f is given by
$$
\int f\, d\mu=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n2^n}\frac{k-1}{2^n}\mu\left(\left\{\omega\in\Omega: \frac{k-1}{2^n}\leq f(\omega)<\frac{k}{2^n}\right\}\right).
$$

Hey! Here's my proof. Would you please tell me, if it is okay?

Define
$$
A_{k,n}:=\left\{\omega\in\Omega|\frac{k-1}{2^n}\leq f(\omega)<\frac{k}{2^n}\right\}
$$
and with that
$$
f_n:=\sum_{k=1}^{n2^n}\frac{k-1}{2^n}1_{A_{k,n}}.
$$
$f_n$ is measurable, because $A_{k,n}\in\mathcal{A}$, because of the measurability of $f$. Moreover, $f_n$ is non-negative and only takes finite many values; so $f_n$ is an elementary function.

Furthermore, $A_{k,n}\cap A_{j,n}=\emptyset$ for $j,k\in\left\{1,\ldots,n2^n\right\}, j\neq k$ and
$$
A_{k,n}=A_{2k-1,n+1}\uplus A_{2k,n+1}\text{ for }k=1,\ldots,n2^n.
$$
So consider any $n$ and any $x\in A_{k,n}$ for any $k\in\left\{1,\ldots,n2^n\right\}$. Then
$$
f_n(x)=\frac{k-1}{2^n}
$$
and 
$$
f_{n+1}(x)=\frac{k-1}{2^{n-2}}\vee f_{n+1}(x)=\frac{k}{2^{n-2}}-\frac{1}{2^{n-1}},
$$
so $f_n(x)\leq f_{n+1}(x)$, i.e. $(f_n)_{n\geq 1}$ increases.

Consider $n>f(x)$ for any $x\in\Omega$ (this works, because $f$ is bounded). Then
$$
f_n(x)\leq f(x)<f_n(x)+2^{-n}.
$$
So for $n\to\infty$ it is $2^{-n}\to 0$ and therefore
$$
f_n(x)=f(x).
$$
So $f_n\uparrow f$.

Now I apply monotone convergence and the definition of the Lebesgue-integral for elementary functions, getting
$$
\int f\, d\mu=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_n\, d\mu=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n2^n}\frac{k-1}{2^n}\mu(A_{k,n}).
$$

$\diamondsuit$